# Customizing the Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, themes, elementaryos

I am using Elementary OS (based on Ubuntu 12.04) and i would like to change the coloring scheme for Pantheon Terminal window.

Here's what i have tried-

1. Elementary Tweaks
2. Dconf Editor
3. shell commands

None of them are getting the job done. 
It's extremely difficult for me to differentiate between a command prompt and other text.

This is what I would like to use

https://github.com/Mayccoll/Elementary-OS-Terminal-Colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizing terminal colors via Tweaks/Dconf globally changes the colors of all terminal application. For example `mc` is completely unusable with the preinstalled terminal themes (at least for me).

> It's extremely difficult for me to differentiate between a command prompt and other text.

In this case, you should take a look your `~/.bashrc` file and try uncomment  `force_color_prompt=yes`. This should give a colorized prompt after restarting terminal.

Change colors and other properities of the bash prompt, just edit in `.bashrc`:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$ '
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Answer (score 1):

You may also try guide from [Mayccoll](https://github.com/Mayccoll/Elementary-OS-Terminal-Colors/), downloading and installing complete script.

First uncomment the following line in **.bashrc**:

```
 #force_color_prompt=yes
```

And then install style:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mayccoll/Elementary-OS-Terminal-Colors/master/elementary.sh
$ chmod +x elementary.sh
$ ./elementary.sh
```

Replace **elementary.sh** with style that is available in the Mayccoll's Git.

Another way is to open style that you want to install and import values manually trough dconf:

**org** -> **gnome** -> **pantheon** -> **terminal** -> **settings**

Values are:

```
background_color - background
foreground_color - foreground
palette - palette
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to theme my terminal, only dconf tools worked for me. executing individual bash scripts didn't do anything.

Comment: Glad that worked for you!